# Event listener entity selected in one class and I want to transfer it to a another class

Tags: java, minecraft

The title is misleading I think, wasn't quite sure how to put this. I'm new.
I'm making a plugin for a minecraft server in eclipse, and i have an event listener

```
package me.rumic.speedrun.commands;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEntityEvent;

import me.rumic.speedrun.Main;

public class PlayerSelec implements Listener{
    private Main plugin;
    
    public PlayerSelec(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void plslEvent(PlayerInteractEntityEvent e) {
        Entity ent = e.getRightClicked();
        ent.sendMessage("You have been selected");
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        p.sendMessage("You selected an entity");
        
    }

}
```

With this i right click and an entity is selected. But in a diffrent class i want to call that entity i selected and apply a potion to it.

```
package me.rumic.speedrun.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

import me.rumic.speedrun.Main;

public class WeaknessCommand implements CommandExecutor{
    private Main plugin;
    
    public WeaknessCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("WC").setExecutor(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        ent.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.WEAKNESS, 200, 1));
        return false;
    }

}
```

I thought maybe someway I could import it but I really have no idea. If somebody could please help, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first the code of your Listener looks a bit odd. Normally you register your events in the main class in the `onEnable()` function. So you can be sure it gets registered. You would also have to make some changes to your listener. I'd suggest something like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractAtEntityEvent event) {

    // check if the entity right-clicked is a player
    if (event.getRightClicked().getType().equals(EntityType.PLAYER)) {

        // apply the potion effect
        ent.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.WEAKNESS, 200, 1));
    }
}
```